# Loopback - Angular2 adding accessToken to requests

Tags: angular, loopback

I'm trying to send all queries from frontend to loopback with an access token. I'm using loopback sdk builder for angular2.

After user logins, loopback returns an access token. I use the function above to append that access token to request headers

```
LoopBackConfig.setAuthPrefix(this.user.accessToken);
```

After that, all requests' headers have a property like that:

```
authorization: Wl3P7ysrfu1tq2gcljezdZRDHH...
```

I have added "loopback#token": {} to "initial:before": in middleware.json

However, still req.accessToken is null. Am I doing something wrong?

And I have one more question. Should access token be in the header? In loopback documents access token is in query parameters. Is there any way to add access token to services created by loopback sdk builder by default?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line solved the problem I think.

```
app.use(loopback.token());
```

Now, AccessToken.findForRequest is called by for each request. And if there is an access token in headers, in cookies or in the url, req.accessToken is created.

In the frontend, I use LoopBackConfig.setAuthPrefix function to put access token into header. For EventSource requests, (since it does not have an api to set header of the request) I add access token to url.

```
let source = new EventSource("/route/event?access_token=" + self.auth.getToken().id);
```

https should be used to avoid security leaks if you send access_token by these methods.

Comment: How did you used the  LoopBackConfig.setAuthPrefix() function?

Comment: hello, i stopped working on that project 2 years ago. so I cannot remember well.but  as far as i see in the latest version of the code I have, i have commented out that line. probably it did not work and i changed to auth.setToken() and and auth.setUser(). auth is LoopBackAuth service

Comment: Ok thanks, probably this is a issue that can be fixed only within the backend